# SQL Access 2010 Calculate Stock Daily Gap

Tags: sql, time-series

I have a table like:

Ticker,
Date,
Open_Price,
Close_Price

which contains 100s of tickers.  I want to add another calculated column called Gap, which is Open_price - Yesterday's close price. For each row (ie each ticker, every day)

Can anyone please help me with the SQL?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? MySql? Somwething else?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that works in many dialects of SQL:

```
select t.*, open_price - lastclose as gap
from (select t.ticker, t.date, t.open_price, t.close_price,
             (select t.close_price from t t2 where t2.ticker = t.ticker and t2.date < t.date order by DATE desc limit 1
             ) as lastclose
      from t
     ) t
```

Depending on the flavor of SQL, the `limit 1` could also be `select top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or . . . even some other possibilities.

This uses a correlated subquery to emulate the `lag()` function, which is what you really need.  If you have this, you can write:

```
select t.*, open_price - lastclose as gap
from (select t.ticker, t.date, t.open_price, t.close_price,
             lag(close_price) over (partition by ticker order by date) as lastclose
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I just installed SQL 2012 to use LAG, and your solution worked a treat.  THanks!

Comment: @user2109074 . . . The enhanced window functions are a great improvement in SQL Server 2012.